# no such file or directory boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm running the [hello world example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html) out of the Boost.Python page.

However I'm getting the error message

```
Cannot open include file: 'boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp': No such file or directory
```

My CMD comand is simply `bjam`

`C:\Program Files\boost_1_66_0\boost\ is in PATH` and prefix.hpp is in `C:\Program Files\boost_1_66_0\boost\python\detail\prefix.hpp`

hello.cpp is as follows:

```
"#include "C:\Program Files\boost_1_66_0\boost\python\module.hpp"
#include "C:\Program Files\boost_1_66_0\boost\python\def.hpp"
#include "C:\Program Files\boost_1_66_0\boost\python\detail\prefix.hpp"


char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot open include file" means that the compiler is trying to open the file `boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp` and it can't find it.

This means you have to tell it where to look. The list of directories in which the compiler looks for include files is call the "include path". While I know this sounds like the `PATH`, it is not the same. `PATH` is used when searching for *executable* files being run from the shell, not for where to look for header files.

What compiler are you're using? The command `bjam` is calls the Boost build system, and unless you're using Cygwin to build, this [is not supported](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).

Try following the directions on the Boost.Python setup pages, such as the [no-install quickstart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/no_install_quickstart.html), as they walk you through debugging multiple types of build errors.

Comment: thanks. I've tried to run it using using both bjam and g++. I'll take a look at the directions you referenced.